# Loading config into a data type and Iterating over type fields to change defaults

Tags: haskell

I currently read config file into its data type using configurator library:

```
import           Data.Configurator             (Worth (Required), getMap, load)
import           Data.Configurator.Types       (convert)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict           as H (empty, lookup)

loadConfig :: IO AppConfig
loadConfig = do
  conf <- load [Required "application.cfg"] >>= getMap
  let cfg def key =  fromMaybe def . maybe (Just def) convert $ H.lookup key conf
  return AppConfig { cfgDBHost     = cfg "localhost" "db-host"
                   , cfgDBName     = cfg "test" "db-name"
                   , cfgSesTime    = cfg 28800 "ses-time"
                   , cfgMailDir    = cfg "./mail" "mail-dir"
                   , cfgDistDir    = cfg "./public" "dist-dir"
                   , cfgIndexHtml  = cfg "index.html" "index-html"
                   , cfgUseTls     = cfg False "use-tls"
                   , cfgTlsPort    = cfg 8443 "tls-port"
                   , cfgTlsKey     = cfg "key.pem" "tls-key"
                   , cfgTlsCrt     = cfg "crt.pem" "tls-crt"
                   , cfgAppPort    = cfg 3000 "app-port"
                   , cfgLDAPHost   = cfg "" "ldap-host"
                   , cfgLDAPDomain = cfg "" "ldap-domain"
                   }
```

So if there is a file parse error or a setting does not exist in the config file, it assigns the default setting to the record field.

My problem is this. I want to initialise `AppConfig` with the defaults in the very beginning and then iterate over fields changing them with the settings loaded from the file. I want to leaving default as it is in case of an error or if setting does not exist in the file.

I guess the question is can I iterate over record fields?
If it is possible, what is the best solution to the above problem?
To summarise. I want to fill the record fields with the default settings, read the configuration file, override the record fields with the available settings from the config file.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what difference is there between writing the defaults first or not? In either case, each field will contain the value from the file, if it exists, and the default otherwise. If you really wanted to do this, you would need to construct the default app config (perhaps `instance Default AppConfig`?) and change `cfg` to *update* the appropriate field in `AppConfig` (i.e. a function `String -> AppConfig -> AppConfig`) which would leave the value unchanged if the key isn't found in the file. Of course, this seems much harder than what you have now.

Comment: `H.lookupDefault "localhost" "db-name" conf`.